# Ros Hydro on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using a ubuntu 14.04 and I have bought the book "Ros By Example Hydro-Volume 1". Is there any possible ways for me to download Ros Hydro in my computer?? and even though in can't is the Ros indigo very different with hydro?? Is it okay to use the hydro book on the Ros indigo??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205661/ros-hydro-on-ubuntu14.04/) by [Vito 178](https://answers.ros.org/users/21952/vito-178/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am currently using a ubuntu 14.04 [..]

and:

> Is there any possible ways for me to download Ros Hydro in my computer??

Short answer: no, Hydro can only be installed on Ubuntu versions 12.04 (Precise), 12.10 (Quantal) and 13.04 (Raring).

See also [REP-003: Platforms by Distribution](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#platforms-by-distribution).

As to whether you can read a book for Hydro while using Indigo: @Wolf's answer is correct: there is not too much difference between the two, but you will run into some (minor) changes that you'll have to account for. At the very least you'll have to replace every occurrence of `hydro` in (pkg names fi) with `indigo`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-03-23**:
+1 for noticing the correct ubuntu version, óf course my response does only apply if OS version is not specified;)